# Protecting Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Looking for a solution to protecting an access database.  I want a user to be able to read and write to it via a vb.net program but when a user goes to the location of the database, on a network folder, they cannot interact with it there.

I know I can password protect the database and include the password in the connection string but with enough effort would the user be able to find said password in the program's files once installed on their computer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: very little you can do - you could set up an ODBC DSN and put the PW in there, but that moves the problem elsewhere. it's access - it's a file-based DB, and there's not much you can do to protect it.

Comment: The user is technically adept enough to decompile your program? If so, then at most you could obfuscate the source and build in some encryption/decryption of the password to make it much harder to trace. That's what I do...sure someone with the skillset could get at my code, but the important parts are gibberish and it's very hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Which version of Access?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Would it be better t try and switch to another DB format if so what? Sorry if that's broad.

Comment: @Plutonix 2010 version

Comment: @Plutonix: Use account security has been disabled since Access 2007.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks, I thought they removed it more recently than that.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by *Marc B*, you can add some twists and that's it. It will only be *bumps*, not real security.

The simple and effective solution is to move your data to a server based database engine with true security. As you use *VB.NET*, the natural choice would be the free *SQL Server 2014 Express*.

Comment: Yes.  SQL Server Express comes with your copy of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It might not work however it is worth a try before setting up something new, i was thinking since you mentioned that the file is on a network why not try and encrypt the file each time the program closes? that way if a another user was to locate it on the network on another computer they shouldn't be able to access it.

```
Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    Dim FileLocation As String = "C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Documents\Database1.accdb"
    IO.File.Encrypt(FileLocation)
End Sub
```

If you wanted to decrypt the file, just replace encrypt with decrypt.
Also add a password from access as mentioned above.
This is about all you can do I believe, let us know how you get on.